# what library to use for stoi keyword in c++

Tags: c++, string, int, sstream

my question is pretty simple but I can't seem to find it out.
I want to know what libary to include when using `stoi`. I was using `atoi` and it works fine with

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
```

but I get "stoi not declared" when I run with `stoi`. Thanks

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: Show your code. `std::stoi` is actually declared in `<string>`. Also, it was introduced in C++11, so that might be the problem.

Comment: Don't mix C and C++ headers; use `<cstdlib>` instead.

Comment: `std::stoi` is a standard library *function*, not a keyword. A [keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword) is something like `for` or `new`.

Comment: I guess thats why it cannot compile. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#include <string>` and use a compiler that understands C++11.  Minimal example:

```
#include <string>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
  std::string example = "1234";
  int i = std::stoi(example);
  assert(i == 1234);
  return 0;
}
```

Compile, for example, with `g++ -std=c++11`.